# Openlaszlo html tag AIR issue

Tags: air, openlaszlo, lzx

I just developed a sample **openlaszlo** application containing HTML tag loading openlaszlo site. And i developed a sample air application having another html tag and i loaded the openlaszlo application through the air application. For some reason i am not able to see the html content of the openlaszlo application.

Has anyone come across this kind of issues?

Comment: Do you mean an OpenLaszlo SWF application compiled into an Adobe AIR app, or did bundle a DHTML application into an AIR app? In case of the SWF runtime, I doubt that anyone ever tested use of the <html> tag with the embedded Webkit browser in the AIR runtime.  
Do you see any error or log messages when launching the app?

Comment: @RajuBitter: It's a swf application. I didn't get any error. But i did notice one thing. When i refresh the page i am able to see the html. The html is behind the swf. I tried all things but i am not able to get it above the swf. I am actually trying to get the html source that is rendered throught the air browser.

Comment: @RajuBitter: I am using a similar browser like this https://bitbucket.org/jeffreypalermo/adobeairwithflex4demo/src/3a195081307e/src/HeadspringDemo.mxml

Comment: I am not sure if this will solve your problem but have you set wmode of the SWF to transparent? wmode="transparent" If stuff is showing up behind the Flash this will fix it sometimes.

Comment: @Kmeixner: Did the trick...Its working thank you...Can you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@karthick In your comments on your question you stated that "The html is behind the SWF": The solution to this problem is to set the *Window Mode* attribute of the SWF (Flash) object to "transparent":

Example:

a) Direct Flash  embed syntax:

```
<object ...>
...
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
</object>
```

b) OpenLaszlo JavaScript embed syntax:

```
lz.embed.swf({
              url: 'http://www.mysite.com/myapp.lzx.swf10.swf?lzr=swf10', wmode: 'transparent', ... });
```